# Can it be argued that mathematics was discovered and the study was for the most part, ancient Indian scientists?

Tags: india

Numerous evidence that many mathematical knowledge was known to Indians long before the Europeans (binomial coefficients, trigonometric formulas, complex numbers, and so on) has been preserved. Why do many argue that the priority in the discovery belongs to the Europeans?

Comment: It's generally a good idea to cite your sources. Unsupported statements like "Numerous evidence..." often attract down-votes & close-votes.  In fact, most people credit the ancient Egyptians and Babylonians.  See, for example the [Rhind Mathematical Papyrus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhind_Mathematical_Papyrus) dating from c. 1650 BCE but probably actually a copy of an older document from about 2000–1800 BCE.

Comment: 'Can it be argued' is an opening for debating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern math has a continuous thread of development from the Greeks &c through the Arabs to Europe and today's math.  Indian math (if indeed it did exist as you claim) was independent of this thread, and (with a few exceptions such as the idea of zero & positional notation) seems to have died out without making any contribution to modern math.

It's like claiming that the ancient Egyptian pyramid builders, or the folks who built Stonehenge and other Neolithic monuments, must have known a great deal about engineering.  But whatever they did know is lost.  Their techniques aren't taught in engineering school.